# parsley.js how to trigger an error on a field with a custom error message

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, parsley.js

It would be great if it was possible to do such thing as

```
$('input.specific-field').parsley('error', 'this is a custom error message');
```

...but I guess that isn't possible?

How could I achive such thing?

Answer (score 16):

Parsley has some built-in ways of adding custom error messages.

```
var specificField = $('input.specific-field').parsley();
# add the error
window.ParsleyUI.addError(specificField, "myCustomError", 'this is a custom error message');
# remove the error
window.ParsleyUI.removeError(specificField, "myCustomError");
```

More info here: http://parsleyjs.org/doc/index.html#psly-ui-for-javascript

**EDIT**: [This method is now deprecated](https://github.com/guillaumepotier/Parsley.js/issues/1073) (thanks to @giraff).

Comment: This method is deprecated: https://github.com/guillaumepotier/Parsley.js/issues/1073

Answer (score 4):

This is how I got it working for Parsley 2.8:

```
field.parsley().removeError('customValidationId');
field.parsley().addError('customValidationId', {message: "myCustomError"});
```

http://parsleyjs.org/doc/index.html#psly-ui-for-javascript

Here is a turnkey-solution that I used for showing error from AJAX to fields identified by their id:

```
// Removing errors from previous AJAX call
if ($('.js_error').length) {
    $('.js_error').parsley().removeError('myError');
    $('.js_error').removeClass('.js_error');
}

// Showing errors from current AJAX call
for (var idField in ajaxErrors) {
    var msg = ajaxErrors[idField];
    var field = $('#field_' + idField);
    if (field.length) {
        field.addClass('js_error');
        field.parsley().removeError('myError');
        field.parsley().addError('myError', {message: msg});
    }
}
```

This solution will not prevent form-submit, though (because it only displays error messages in the UI, the form validation logic is not touched). That's why [Parsley.js favors custom validators](https://github.com/guillaumepotier/Parsley.js/issues/1073).

Answer (score 2):

maybe this:

```
$('input.specific-field').parsley().UI.manageError({error: 'this is a custom error message'});
```

Comment: or maybe $('input.specific-field').parsley().UI.addError({error: 'this is a custom error message'});, i had the same problem with displaying custom error after server respond. - I found this post : https://github.com/guillaumepotier/Parsley.js/issues/440

Comment: EDIT seems this only works if the field has been invalidated before

Comment: this seems to work but I'm not sure how 'correct' it is to do so:

$('#register-email').parsley().UI.manageError({
    error: null
});

$('#register-email').parsley().UI.addError({
    error: 'Emailadresse bereits vergeben'
});

Comment: Continuing this thread of bumping what worked, for me it was `$('...').parsley().UI.manageErrorContainer().addError({err: 'Name cannot be blank'})`

Comment: With the current version of Parsley (2.8) this errors as `$('...').parsley().UI is undefined`

Answer (score 2):

```
data-parsley-error-message="my message"
```

worked for me see
http://parsleyjs.org/doc/index.html#ui-for-javascript for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Examples above appear to be for Parsley 2.0
I'm stuck with an older version but got custom errors to work with the following.

```
el = $('#my_input').parsley();
el.manageErrorContainer(); // set up the error list container
$(el.ulError).empty() // clear any previous errors if you want..
el.addError({error: 'Hey, mind yerself!'});
```